# Charge Qubit vs Transmon

Tags: experimental-realization

I want to know the big difference, in terms of fabrication (circuit) between a charge Qubit and a Transmon, how is a Transmon less affected by noise ?

Many thanks

Comment: Very sleepy forum... and very amateur also, far from professionalism !!!